# Why can't I answer this question that I originally asked?

Tags: support, answers

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error) a long time ago. It got closed because it seemed as though the problem had gone away. However, the problem resurfaced so I requested that it be opened again. And it was - the `[Closed]` status and label was removed, the question was **re-opened** (as far as I can tell).

Now, thanks to the [help and support I got through another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122148/flash-in-browsers-does-not-play-sound-accurately-using-pulse-network-audio), I think I have a definite answer as to why I was having this problem. So I thought that the cool thing to do would be to put an answer in and give what I think is the definitive explanation for what was happening. I think I can also generalize the lessons I learned so that it's useful for others.

However, the button to add an answer is not visible, at least to me.

I thought maybe because I had awarded some recent bounties that reduced my reputation, and maybe I fell below a permission threshold for answering one's own questions or something like that. However, reading through the FAQ, I can't see any obvious reason why I can't answer this question.

I think it would be better to provide an answer as there are 5 upvotes and maybe others are having the same issue. I don't particularly care if the answer comes from me or not, I just think it would be best for there to be more information for people to consider.

How can I answer this question?

---

Here is a screenshot of what I see. Unless I'm mistaken, the "Add an answer" or "answer your own question" button should be at the bottom of other answers.

[image]

Comment: Can we have a screenshot of what you see in that question? Make sure you have logged in your account. I am guessing this is probably a login issue or a cache issue.

Comment: @jokerdino: I am definitely logged in, and I refreshed my browser cache to be sure that I'm not seeing old data. Also, this problem has been manifest consistently for a few days. I've added a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have 10 reputation *excluding the 100 rep account association bonus* in order to answer protected questions.  So you just need a bit more rep to hit 110 and you'll be good.

See the last point in [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question.
>   However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check,
>   so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to
>   answer a protected question.

Comment: Well, that would explain it then. So here's an interesting situation - Here's an issue I do know something about, but I can't answer it until I earn reputation, which is difficult since I don't know much about anything else, because that's the whole reason I'm on this forum.

Comment: @DaveMG It looks like you should be able to post now.  Want to give it a try?

Comment: I assume that was you who upvoted a few questions or answers of mine to put me over the top? Cheers for that. ;)